# Excel VBA: Find empty cell and delete the row

Tags: vba, excel

I have vertical data with gaps in columns B:G

I wish that my code does the following:

1. Screens through column B
2. Find an empty cell
3. Deletes the entire row of the empty cell
4. Repeat this until 10 empty cells are found (that's the trickiest, as it should not delete these 10 empty cells) //10 is just an arbitrary number that there is no more data
5. Then go to column C repeat the full proces and so on until all columns are screened

I have some basic VBA knowledge and this is the code I have found on the subject so far, however it's a mess in my head how to approach this.

The main issue I am having is how would the code know when to stop deleting and move to the next column.

This code below finds the next empty cell in column B and selects it.

```
Public Sub SelectFirstBlankCell()
Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

sourceCol = 6   'column F has a value of 6
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
        Exit For 'This is missing...
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub SelectFirstBlankCell()
Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

For i = 0 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'count and loop cols

    sourceCol = 1 + i 'increment with i, move 1 to start column
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For currentRow = rowCount To 1 Step -1 ' this will start at end and work its way up

        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value

        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Or Trim(currentRowValue) = "" Then 'Trim accounts for " " may not be needed
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Try above. sourceCol = 1 + i can be changed to sourceCol = x + i where x is your start column