# How to delete rows based on empty cell value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, null

I am trying to delete entire rows based on whether the cell value in the D column is NULL or not. My entire code so far is:

```
Sub DeleteNULL()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 119713
        If IsEmpty(Range("Di")) = True Then
             Rows([i]).EntireRow.Delete

        Else
            If IsEmpty(Range("Di")) = False Then
            Next i

        End If


End Sub
```

I keep getting compile errors, either If without Else or Next without For, how should I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to loop backwards or you will have issues with it skipping rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462449/excel-vba-find-empty-cell-and-delete-the-row?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. Placement of a lot of syntax is off.
2. When adding or deleting rows, you need to loop backwards based on how Excel handles these events.

See code below:

```
Sub DeleteNULL()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 119713 To 2 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Range("D" & i)) Then Rows([i]).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't Endif and Next must be in swapped position.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - Fixed. Didn't see my typo. Thanks. Was that you who downvoted?

Comment: Never. My thumb rule on SO, If you cant get votes, Never Downvote others.

Comment: okay @AnkitBajpai. Thanks for letting me know. I was curious why it would get downvoted